# Put next months start as previous months end pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in long format (panel data), Each person has a start month along with variables. it looks something like:

### Data description

| person_id | month_start | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.4 | 1.4 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.3 | 0.131 |
| 1 | 3 | 0.34 | 0.434 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.49 | 0.949 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.53 | 1.53 |
| 2 | 5 | 0.38 | 0.738 |
| 3 | 1 | 1.12 | 1.34 |
| 3 | 4 | 1.89 | 1.02 |
| 3 | 5 | 0.83 | 0.27 |

and I need it to look like:

| person_id | month_start | month_end | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 0.4 | 1.4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 0.3 | 0.131 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 0.34 | 0.434 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 0.49 | 0.949 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 | 0.53 | 1.53 |
| 2 | 5 | 6 | 0.38 | 0.738 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 1.12 | 1.34 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 | 1.89 | 1.02 |
| 3 | 5 | 6 | 0.83 | 0.27 |

Where month end is the beginning of the next entry for that person.

I was able to make this:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'person_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 'var1': [0.4, 0.3, 0.34, 0.49, 0.53, 0.38, 1.12, 1.89, 0.83], 'var2': [1.4, 0.131, 0.434, 0.949, 1.53, 0.738, 1.34, 1.02, 0.27], 'month_start': [1,2,3,2,3,5,1,4,5]})

def add_end_date(df_in,object_id, start_col, end_col):
    df = df_in.copy()
    prev_person_id = -1
    prev_index = -1
    df[end_col] = [-1]*len(df)
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        p_id = row[object_id]
        p_idx = idx
        if prev_person_id == p_id:
            df.loc[prev_index, end_col] = int(row[start_col])# put in start date as last entries end date
        if row[end_col] == -1:
            df.loc[idx, end_col] = int(row[start_col]+1)
        prev_person_id = p_id
        prev_index = p_idx
    return df

add_end_date(a, 'person_id', 'month_start', 'month_end')
```

Is there a better/optimized way to accomplish this?

Comment: How does this differ from simply adding a month from start month to create a new column as end month?

Comment: why 6 in the 6th and 9th row in the desired table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `groupby.shift`:

```
df['month_end'] = df.groupby('person_id').month_start.shift(-1)\
                    .fillna(df.month_start + 1).astype(int)

df
   person_id  month_start  Var1   Var2  month_end
0          1            1  0.40  1.400          2
1          1            2  0.30  0.131          3
2          1            3  0.34  0.434          4
3          2            2  0.49  0.949          3
4          2            3  0.53  1.530          5
5          2            5  0.38  0.738          6
6          3            1  1.12  1.340          4
7          3            4  1.89  1.020          5
8          3            5  0.83  0.270          6
```